# Run another MSI from C# setup installer

Tags: c#, .net

I have a set up project which installs my program just fine. However, my project also requires crystal reports. So what I am trying to do is somehow get my installation to call the MSI that will install the runtime while running my setting . I have tried adding crystal reports as a prep requite in the build but that is causing the entire file to be downloaded...i actually do not want that and just want to jump from my install to the install of the other MSI.
Any help setting this up or pointing to a resource that helps would be appreciated...thanks

Comment: Make your app launch it on first run, just like in steam.

Comment: I think you should use bootstrapper installer.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is called "nested installation".
The following link describes how this is done: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306439

Please be aware of the disadvantages of creating a nested installation:

- Nested Installations cannot share components.
- An administrative installation cannot contain a nested installation.
- Patching and upgrading will not work with nested installations.
- The installer will not correctly cost a nested installation.
- Integrated ProgressBars cannot be used with nested installations.
- Resources that are to be advertised cannot be installed by the nested installation.
- A package that performs a nested installation of an application should also uninstall the nested application when the parent product is uninstalled.

I would create a Legacy Bootstrapper which installs the two MSI files.